# Replacement for org.hibernate.Transactions.isActive() in Hibernate 5

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-4.x, hibernate-5.x

I'm migrating from hibernate 4.2.17 to 5.0.7 which works fine so far, but it seems that the method `isActive` is deprecated. I just can't use it anymore.

Here's my code:

```
public void starteTransaktion() {
        try {
            getMySession();

            if(!hibernateSession.getTransaction().isActive()) {
                hibernateSession.beginTransaction();
            }
        } catch (HibernateException e) {

        }
    }
```

I substituted all other methods, but I can't quite find a replacement for this...

Error message: The method `isActive()` is undefined for the type Transaction

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As per [5.0 Javadoc](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.0/javadocs/org/hibernate/resource/transaction/spi/TransactionStatus.html):

`hibernateSession.getTransaction().getStatus() != TransactionStatus.ACTIVE`